# mongoDB sort command not returning correct value

Tags: node.js, mongodb

I am new to node and trying create a post form in node application

**Doubt 1** - I am trying to find the max itemID from the mongoDB in my node application. Its working perfectly fine for all the records having itemID less then 10.but if there are any record having itemID greater than 10 then its returning max itemID as 9 only.I am not understanding why its failing for 2 digits itemID.

**doubt 2** - i am trying to update the record using my itemID only.its returning the error
Cast to ObjectId failed for value "{ itemID: '4' }" at path "_id" for model "Arts"
but if i try to update it using _id then its working fine

```
 //doubt 1
   artModel.find().sort({ itemID: -1 }).limit(1).exec((error, data) => {
          //not getting max itemID for records having itemID greater than 9 
                 try {
                     if (error) {                                
                     res.render("add", { error: true, msg: true })
                     }
                      else {  
                        if (data == '') {
                         maxIdInDB = '1'
                        }
                        else {
                          maxIdInDB = (parseInt(data[0].itemID) + 1).toString();
                        }
                        if (req.body.isHomeDisplay == "on") {
                         artModel.find({ homeDisplay: true }, (error, homeData) => {
                            if (error) {                                        
                              res.render('add', { error: true, msg: true })
                            }
                            else {
                               var totalArtOnHomeTab = homeData.length;
                               if (totalArtOnHomeTab > 7) {                  
                             var updateItemID = parseInt(homeData[0].itemID);
//working perfectly fine for the below line of code
//doubt 2
// artModel.findByIdAndUpdate({ _id : homeData[0].id}, {$set: { homeDisplay: false } }, (error, data) 
      artModel.findByIdAndUpdate({ itemID : homeData[0].itemID}, { $set: { homeDisplay: false } }, 
           (error, data) => {                                                     
                 if (error) {
                 res.render('add', { error: true, msg: true })
                 }
                 else {
                 insertImagesToDB(req,res,maxIdInDB);
                 }
                    })
                 }
                 else { 
                  insertImagesToDB(req,res,maxIdInDB);
                }
                }
                })
                 }
                else {
                insertImagesToDB(req,res,maxIdInDB);
                }
                }
                }
           catch (e) {
                 res.render("add", { error: true, msg: true })
         }
       })
```

any help would be appreciated as i am struck in this from past 2 days

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Doubt1 Solution: you can use   `artModel.find({itemID :{ $gt: 10}} ).sort({ itemID: -1 }).limit(1).exec((error, data) => {});`

Doubt2: you got an Error because you have used **findByIdAndUpdate()** method
https://mongoosejs.com/docs/api.html#model_Model.findByIdAndUpdate

Instead of use **findByIdAndUpdate()** you can simply use  the 
https://mongoosejs.com/docs/tutorials/findoneandupdate.html

and one thing please Format and optimize code as possible and try to make a define the good structure of code you can you '**switch Case**'
Instead of **If Else Statement**
I hope you will get answer your question. thanks :)

Comment: i always want to get max itemID....for eg- if my collection contains maxID like 2,5,6,7,9 then my query is returning 9.but if the maxID in the collection is like 1,5,6,7,8,9,11,12,14 then also its returning maxID as 9

Comment: Doubt1 Ans: your above Query is Absolutely Correct. please try the same Query in MongoDb Intellishelll terminal and check the result. I have Executed the Query and I got the Correct result. I have Shared a scrnshot please check it now


https://drive.google.com/file/d/1YXIRISWL1RAhLGe8d0LuV_MwVjMJjeaE/view

https://drive.google.com/file/d/1YXIRISWL1RAhLGe8d0LuV_MwVjMJjeaE/view

Comment: actually i have set itemID type as string..thats why the query wasnot working....i have changed it to number and now its working fine....

Comment: Okey!.. key DataType is playing an important role in DB when you perform CRUD operations. please go through the  Schema Datatypes I hope this  one help in a Future https://mongoosejs.com/docs/schematypes.html